# Assign the nodes attributes to edge weights using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a directed graph that ends to point '12'. I have calculated all the nodes attribute values based on the out-degree distribution. Now I am not able to assign the node's attribute value to its edges as weights. The help in this regard would be highly appreciated..

Please see the graph attached here.

[image]

These are my sample codes.

```
nodes <- read.csv("test_nodes1.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
links <- read.csv("test_edge1.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
links <- links[order(links$from, links$to),]
G <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes$id, directed=T)


V(G)$dist <- 1 

for (i in V(G)$name) {

  out_deg_i <- degree(G,i, mode = "out")

  if (out_deg_i >1){

    V(G)[i]$dist = V(G)[i]$dist/out_deg_i
  }
  else{
    V(G)[i]$dist =1
  }
 }

 V(G)$name
 V(G)$dist
 
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13"
 [1] 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: It’s OT clear which edge should be given the weight or weights.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need `tail_of` like below

```
G <- set_edge_attr(
    G,
    name = "wt",
    value = 1 / pmax(degree(G, mode = "out"), 1)[names(tail_of(G, E(G)))]
)
```

and you can check the result via

```
plot(G, edge.label = E(G)$wt)
```

[image]

## Data

```
G <- graph_from_data_frame(
    data.frame(
        from = c(1, 2, 4, 4, 4),
        to = c(4, 4, 3, 5, 6)
    )
)
```